# how to store multiple values in a text file in unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ksh

I need to store multiple values in a single text file in a .ksh script
and send that as an attachment in a mail below is a sample code snippet I was working on

```
   function 1
  {
   7za x -p$pass1 $file  -aoa                             
   if [ $? -eq 0 ]; 
then
continue;   
    fi

   7za x -p$pass2 $file -aoa                   
   if [ $? -eq 0 ]; 
   then
   continue;
   fi

    7za x -p$pass4 $file  -aoa                    
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; 
then
continue;
    fi


    # Fallthrough.We get here only if all of the above failed.
attachment=`echo $file >/data/mvr/PRESCREEN/IA/test.txt`  #<-- Note below
echo "File not extracted see attachement" |mailx -s"Failure" -a attachemnt 
     acb@xyz.com
     done
     }
```

Note: In the above code I need to store all the files names which were not extracted in the'test.txt' which will then be sent as an attachment 
The above code sends me the only the last name of the file which was not extracted,instead of listing all the files which were not extracted. how do I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'>' is the replacement operator. It will replace the contents of the target file at every iteration.

'>>' is the concatenation operator. It will add to the contents of the target file.

attachment=`echo $file >>/data/mvr/PRESCREEN/IA/test.txt`

You'll probably want to '/bin/rm /data/mvr/PRESCREEN/IA/test.txt' at the start of your script to keep it from containing data from previous runs.

Comment: so after i do '/bin/rm /data/mvr/PRESCREEN/IA/test.txt' it will clean up the .txt file ?